# How do I get the index of a sortable item dragged into new list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I've got 2 JQueryUI sortable Lists with a one way connection:

```
$("#sortable1").sortable({
  connectWith: "#sortable2",
});

$("#sortable2").sortable({
  receive: function(event, ui) {
    //returns the idx of the ui.item in #sortable1
    var idx = Number($("#sortable2 > div:visible").index(ui.item)) + 1;
    console.log(idx);
  }
});
```

How can I get the index of where the item from `#sortable1` is dropped on `#sortable2`.
I've tried using the `receive` method and searching for the index of the dragged `ui.item` (), but then discovered that the `ui.item` refers to the item being dragged, not the item being dropped.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
Im really moving portlets. Apologies, I (foolishly) assumed that my above example would duplicate the problem Im having. [jsFiddle problem here](http://jsfiddle.net/qc3paf3o/1/)

Comment: Can you make a reproducible example? This does exactly what you want it to: http://jsfiddle.net/qc3paf3o/

Comment: @blgt - Added jsFiddle of the problem. Please help if you can.

Comment: It looks like just a couple of typo-s: http://jsfiddle.net/3o6yvf43/ There's an `#id` selector which isn't in the html, and an invalid `style=` tag attribute

Comment: @blgt - *facepalm* these were stupid mistakes. Thanks alot!
Do you know how to drag from one to the other but still keep the original in its place? I tried the `sortable('cancel')` method on the original list, and that triggered the alert, but then of course cancelled the drag.

Comment: With regular draggables you can `helper:"clone"`, but I'm not sure you can do that with sortable items. It's a whole different question in any case